# Understanding integral of cos x over pi/2 with n = 4

Tags: calculus

I am just starting to learn about integration, and one of the practice problems given is the problem: Use n = 4 rectangles and right endpoints to approximate the area of the region bounded by $f(x)=cos(x), 0 \le x \le {\pi \over 2}$ in the first quadrant.

My understanding of this problem is as follows:
$$
\Delta x = {{\pi \over 2 } - 0\over n} = {{\pi \over 2} - 0 \over 4} = {\pi \over 8}
$$

$$
A \approx \sum_{i=1}^4 f \left({\pi i \over 2n} \right) \left({\pi \over 2n} \right) 
$$

$$
A \approx \left({\pi \over 8} \right) \sum_{i=1}^4 cos \left({\pi i \over 8} \right)  
$$

$$
A \approx \left({\pi \over 8} \right) \left[ cos \left({\pi  \over 8} \right) + cos \left({\pi  \over 4} \right) + cos \left({3\pi  \over 8} \right) + cos \left({\pi  \over 2} \right)  \right] \approx 1.57
$$

However, the answer part of the book gives it the way shown below:

$$
A \approx {\pi \over 8} \left[ cos \left({\pi  \over 8} \right) + cos \left({\pi  \over 4} \right) cos \left({3\pi  \over 8} \right) cos \left({\pi  \over 2} \right)  \right] \approx 0.7908
$$

I do not understand why the last 3 cosines are multiplied this way. How did I set the problem up wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not sure if the book is right...

Comment: The book mistake is just a typo. Your steps are correct but the final answer is incorrect

Comment: yes, I realize now that I had my calculator in degree mode... so sad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expression for $A$ is correct, but numerical value of it is off:

[image]

Comment: had my calculator in degree mode... unfortunate. Bonus points for mathematica explanation as I am trying to learn how to use that better. Didn't even know about Epilog!